# How to submit multiple images with drag and drop and Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, image, drag-and-drop, drag

I am working with multiple images upload with drag and drop and laravel.

Uploading works fine when I select images using control+Select-multiple images. When selecting images one by one or drag images one by one only the last image is uploading.

This is my script and html section for Drag and Drop.

```js
const dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone');
const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
const thumbnailContainer = document.getElementById('thumbnail-container');

dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  dropZone.classList.add('dragover');
});

dropZone.addEventListener('dragleave', () => {
  dropZone.classList.remove('dragover');
});

dropZone.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  dropZone.classList.remove('dragover');

  const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
  fileInput.files = files; // Set the dropped files to the file input
  handleFiles(files);
});

fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const files = e.target.files;
  handleFiles(files);
});

function handleFiles(files) {
  const thumbnails = []; // Array to store generated thumbnails

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i];
    if (file.type.startsWith('image/')) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        const thumbnail = createThumbnail(reader.result);
        thumbnails.push(thumbnail); // Add thumbnail to the array
        if (thumbnails.length === files.length) {
          // Append all thumbnails to the thumbnailContainer
          thumbnails.forEach((thumb) => {
            thumbnailContainer.appendChild(thumb);
          });
        }
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="drop-zone" class="drop-zone">
  <input type="file" id="file-input" multiple name="img[]">
  <h3><i class="bi bi-cloud-arrow-up-fill"></i></h3>
  <p for="file-input" class="drop-zone-label">Drag and drop files here or click to browse</p>
</div>
<div id="thumbnail-container" class="thumbnail-container"></div>
```

Laravel code for uploading multiple images

```
foreach ($request->file('img') as $image) {
          $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = Str::slug($lastInsertId) . '-' . Str::random(8) . '.' . $extension;
        $folderPath = 'property_images/' . $lastInsertId . '/';
        if (!Storage::exists($folderPath)) {
            Storage::makeDirectory($folderPath, 0755, true);
        }
        $resizedImage = Image::make($image)->fit(800, 600)->encode();
        Storage::put($folderPath . $filename, $resizedImage->encoded);
}
```